# Angular application goes blank when added import for @azure/msal-angular

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-ad-msal

I'm starting a new Angular app. It renders as expected at localhost:4200, until I turn this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderBannerComponent,
    MainContentComponent,
    FooterContentinfoComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

into this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderBannerComponent,
    MainContentComponent,
    FooterContentinfoComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MsalModule.forRoot({                                                  // added
      clientID: msal.clientId,                                            // added
      authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${msal.tenantId}/`,   // added
    })                                                                    // added
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Nonetheless, the server says it 'Compiled successfully'. No exception is shown. But all my HTML vanishes and browser at localhost:4200 renders a completely blank page.

Any heads up?

Comment: Nothing in the browser console either?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know exceptions would show there. I'll try to understand what's going on by myself, I think that will help me to learn things.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I upgraded to Angular 15 and suddenly the same problem. Even the index page won't load. Just a white screen and the browser hangs. Only I have no runtime exceptions and the browser goes into infinite loading. I spent a  lot of time trail and error to find out that msal is the problem. When I removed all msal code the site works, but then I cannot connect the the backend anymore. I have a slight more complex setup. I have an interceptor to pass the credentials to the API.

```
 providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: MsalInterceptor,
    multi: true,
  },
  {
    provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'nl-BE'
  },
  {
    provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
    useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory
  },
  {
    provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
    useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory
  },
  {
    provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
    useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory
  },
  MsalService,
  MsalGuard,
  MsalBroadcastService],
```

I have at the moment no clue what dependancies are giving the problem. I migrated another project to angular 15 with the same kind of implementation and there everything still works. So it must be a dependancy problem. Anybody some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MikeOne's comment on my question, I figured out the problem was in my dependecies. Thank you very much.

Comment: So, you encountered a run time exception!! Compiled successfully tells you that compilation is successful but it may throw exceptions at run time (if anything goes wrong). Tip: always keep the console window of the browser open while coding or debugging.